# Returning a callback from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Sorry for the newbie question:

I'm using `useEffect` to avoid setting state on an unmounted component, and I was wondering why does this work:

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true
        actions.getCourseDetails(fullUrl)
            .then(data => {
                if (isMounted) {
                    actions.setOwner(data.course.Student.id);
                    setDetails(data.course);
                }
            });
        return () => {
            isMounted = false;
        }
    }, [actions, fullUrl]);
```

...but when I return a variable instead of a callback it doesn't work?:

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true
        actions.getCourseDetails(fullUrl)
            .then(data => {
                if (isMounted) {
                    actions.setOwner(data.course.Student.id);
                    setDetails(data.course);
                }
            });
        isMounted = false;
        return isMounted;     //returning a variable instead of a callback
    }, [actions, fullUrl]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1. The returned function is used to clean up the effect when the component unmounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `useEffect` is to optionally return a dispose function. React will call this dispose function **ONLY** when one of the dependencies changes or when it unmounts. to "release" stuff that no longer relevant.

For example, you want to wait X seconds after the render, and then change the state:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setTimeout(() => setState('Timeout!', timeToWait));
}, [timeToWait])
```

Imagen that this component mounts and then after one second unmounts. Without a dispose function the timer will run and React will try to run setState on unmounted component, this will result in an error.

The proper way to do it is to use the dispose function:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const id = setTimeout(() => setState('Timeout!', timeToWait));
   return () => clearTimeout(id);
}, [timeToWait])
```

So every time the `timeToWait` dependency changes for some reason, the dispose function will stop the timer and the next render will create a new one with the new value. or when the component unmounts.

In your example, the order of execution will be:

1. Define `isMounted` and set it to `true`
2. Start async action (this will run next tick)
3. Set `isMounted` to `false`
4. return a variable (Not a function)

So you have 2 problems in your (Not-working) example. you don't return a dispose function, and you change `isMounted` to `false` almost immediately after you define it. when the promise will run the `isMounted` will be `false` no matter what. If you'd use a dispose function (The working example), only when React will call it the `isMounted` to turn to `false`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation ;) @gilamran